# Track highlighting text on ubuntu desktop

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, listener, highlight

Need to *listen* an *event* when user selects text in **whole** system, not only in my application. Is there a way to perfom it by `javafx` forces? For example, the google translater chrome extension can instant translate selected text, so application might work with text like that

Comment: Would the operating system even know of such things? I would expect text selection to be an application-level function.

Comment: For an application to know what you are doing (selecting text, clicking etc.) in other applications would be dangerous wouldn't it. I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Ok, may be, it's not enabled by javafx instruments, but is it possible by other tools? I think, for example, class System, or something in that way

Comment: I think you misunderstood @JimS and I. We don't believe the OS is capable, nor should it be capable, of the behavior you want. Granted, we haven't provided an official source, and thus can be mistaken, but _I_ was unable to find a reference saying this _is_ possible. What exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps if you [edit] your question to include the use case someone may be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: Is the Chrome extension capable of translating text selected in _any_ application or _only text selected in Chrome itself_?